# How to parse an XML that has HTML tags in its value using Boost ptree C++

Tags: html, c++, xml, boost

I want to parse the following XML using Boost Ptree

```
<MsgTxt>
<Abc>123</Abc>
<Text>This is my <b>Text</b></Text>
</MsgTxt>
```

However, when i iterate through the XML and use `Message = v.second.get_value <std::string>("Text");`, the HTML tag and its contents get truncated. The value i get is "This is my ".

How can i parse HTML tags like  and  as part of my value through boost ptree

Answer (score 2):

From the point of view of the XML parser there really is no difference between <Text> and <b>. The <b> section therefore becomes just another property in your property tree. Properly layed out, it looks like this:

```
<MsgTxt>
    <Abc>123</Abc>
    <Text>This is my 
        <b>Text</b>
    </Text>
</MsgTxt>
```

According to your question, you really want the <b> to be content, not XML markup. If so, you should encode it as content - and not as markup. This is easy:

```
<MsgTxt>
<Abc>123</Abc>
<Text>This is my &lt;b&gt;Text&lt;/b&gt;</Text>
</MsgTxt>
```

The XML parser will convert those `&lt;` and `&gt;` back into the correct text for you.

With incorrect encoding you will also run into a problem if you have unbalanced tags, i.e. something like

```
<MsgTxt>
<Abc>123</Abc>
<Text>This is my <b>Text</b><br></Text>
</MsgTxt>
```

This is improper XML, and the XML parser will refuse to parse it at all. Again, this can be avoided by using proper encoding of content.

For proper encoding, make sure you encode the following characters:

```
< &lt;
> &gt;
& &amp;
" &quot;
' &apos;
```

Interestingly, the same markup rules apply here in the stackoverflow editor, and I had to go back and replace my < by `&lt;` to make it display properly ;-)